# Rails 4 Unpermitted parameters: products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, strong-parameters

I need to save an array into my `order.rb` model.

The array is: `params[:products]`

The array is giving me something like this:

```
[{"'name'"=>"31 DVIE33N - Traditional ", "'id'"=>"2", "'quantity'"=>"1", "'accessory'"=>{"'id'"=>"7", "'name'"=>"31-SK4BLANKD-2"}}]
```

Create action:

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to admin_orders_path(@order), notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end
```

My orders params.

```
private
    def order_params
      params.permit({:products=>[], products:[])
    end
```

**I'm trying two different ways to permite products, that why you will see two arrays above**

**Please take a look, I'm not using somethig like:**

```
params.require(:order).permit(:products => []}, :products=>[])
```

because if I use that I get the error:

`ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: order:`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in a Rails way...

In models/order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, allow_destroy: true
end
```

In orders_controller.rb

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(products_attributes: [:name, :etc])
end
```

In `products_attributes` array you can pass the product attributes you want to permit.

You need to send `product_attributes` like this: `{“order”=>{“products_attributes"=>[{“name”=>”product 1”}, {“name”=>”product 2”}]}}`

Comment: Hi  @Leantraxxx, I added the relathionship to order model.

I don't get it about "products_attributes"., Why I need to put this into "products_controller". Sorry about that part, but I don't get it. ":listing", "product_attributes: []"

Thanks

Comment: Actually. If I use: params.require in my "orders_controller" I get the error: ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: order:

Comment: Sorry It's `orders_controller`

Comment: you get a `ParameterMissing` error because you are not passing the `order` attribute with all the data in it

Comment: if you use `require(:order)` you need to pass `{“order”=>{“products_attributes"=>[{“name”=>”product 1”}, {“name”=>”product 2”}]}}` if you don't use `require(:order)` you can pass: `{“products_attributes"=>[{“name”=>”product 1”}, {“name”=>”product 2”}]}`

Comment: See the last example: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html I think is what you are looking for

Comment: Sorry 2 :P the `listing` word was copy/paste garbage

Comment: So, somethig like: 

def order_params
  params.permit(:order=>products:[])
end

Sorry, right now I have around 27 hours without sleep. I feel really slow now but I really need to finish this. I really appreciate your help  @Leantraxxx

Comment: you need to pass products_attributes instead of products. see the link before

Comment: Thans for your help